# Jquery getting position().top of div with :not(.class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, css-position

I have problem using the

```
:not(.disabled)
```

in the class selector. After using it I can't get

```
$(this).position().top
```

Here is the code

```
    $('.game:not(.disabled)').bind('click', function(){
    // Note, there is also scrollToX and scrollToY methods if you only
    // want to scroll in one dimension
    $('.game').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var newgame = $(this).attr('data-href');
    theGame = newgame;
    console.log('EVENT: [CHANGED] ['+theGame+']');

    var y = $(this).position().top;
    console.log('EVENT: [SCROLLTO]['+0+' : '+y+']');
    console.log(y);

    api.scrollTo(0, y);
        return false;
    });
```

When I remove :not(.disabled) it works fine and the 'y' coord is used fine..

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sqttzgvp/)

```
$('.game').not('.disabled').on('click', function(){
```

Remember to use .on instead of .bind (for several versions of jQuery now...)

Comment: That was useful. I fixed it by using the position of the <li> element instead of the <a> bellow since the css I applied on the li obviously f'ed things up..